# oEmbed with Mobile devices

Tags: flash, mobile, youtube, rtsp, oembed

I've just found out about oEmbed and was wondering if there is a way to get a mobile link/embed code by sending the user-agent (or preferred format, like 3gp)?

I've might have missed something, but I can't find those options on the oEmbed website.

For example (Youtube), I would like to get the 3gp rtsp link for devices that supports that and flash embed for devices that supports that.

I know those links exists on youtube, because when I go to www.youtube.com with my mobile phone i get links to rtsp.

Thanks.

Comment: been wondering that myself.  I didn't see anything - have you tried spoofing the user-agent and calling the oEmbed API to see if it makes a difference?

Comment: No, but I did get that thought an hour ago. Will try that and get back with the result.

Comment: Did not work, tried with SonyEricssonK810i (user agent), which does not support flash and still got "application/x-shockwave-flash" object.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for your use case, the oembed spec doesn't make any mention of requesting different formats of the content at a given URL, so it's completely up to each provider to decide if & how they want to support mobile-friendly embed code in their responses.

For example, you can pass an iframe parameter to the YouTube oembed endpoint to either the Flash or the iframe version of their embed code. However, I don't think many other providers support this type of flag.

```
# The URL for the Flash version of this video's embed code
http://www.youtube.com/oembed?iframe=0&url=http%3A//youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DaWPoJ6sm8HU&format=json
# The URL for the iframe/mobile-friendly version of this video's embed code
http://www.youtube.com/oembed?iframe=1&url=http%3A//youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DaWPoJ6sm8HU&format=json
```